# Вопросы по разработке браузерок. JS, Django, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, django, webbrowser

Я новичок в программировании и задам, вероятно, очень глупый для бывалого программиста вопрос,а скорее даже вопросы, но ответа в сети я так и не нашел. 
Обучаясь программированию, я попутно создаю небольшую браузерную игру. Сервер я начал писать на django т.к. посмотрев на php я особо ничего не понял, а в гайдах по джанге рекомендуют его многофункциональность и "коробочность". 
Вопрос - django подходит только для backend части или frontend тоже можно на нем писать? Сейчас я говорю именно про механики игры. Например, убийство мобов, торговля меж игроками и.т.п. Если можно, то нужен ли js в таком случае? Я открывал сайт игры, подобие которой хотел бы сделать, и в ее коде элемента не нашел ссылок на полноценные js файлы, которые бы влияли именно на геймплей, лишь массивы с различными внутриигровыми статусами и сообщениями. Неужели это из-за того, что ее механики написаны на php или механику игры все же нельзя написать ни на джанге, ни на php? Если это так, то почему я не смог найти js файлы механик в коде элемента? 
Вообще я был бы очень благодарен, если бы этот пост не заминусовали (ну он, объективно, глупый, я сам это понимаю, но мне нужен ответ) и ответили на вопросы. Может есть какие-то ссылки на гайды по созданию браузерных игр? Может кто-то просто опишет, что для чего нужно?

Comment: Механика на сервере для борьбы с читерами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP или Django нужны для того чтобы связать игру с базой.

Используй Javascript! Если хочешь создать браузерную мультиплеер игру, то советую использовать Socket IO.

Тут 2D игра на socket.io: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEYEpledOxs